# How to import GWT source code into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, open-source, ide

I'm trying to contribute to GWT Open Source project. I'm in the very beginning step in importing the project into eclipse and learning how it works.

The GWT Source Code Repository can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/checkout

However, there are only ant build files in the source code and there aren't any project file there. I believe we do not usually edit the source files in ... notepad and then compile using javac (correct me if i'm wrong). Hence, I wonder how a normal open source contributor usually do to open the source code in his/her favorite IDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Detailed instructions for Eclipse 3.X can be found in the file {svn_working_copy}/trunk/eclipse/README.txt

> there aren't any project file there

It's not true. Import "Existing Project into Workspace" from {svn_working_copy}/trunk/eclipse, then check projects that you want to import (probably gwt-user and gwt-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you ca find the detailed Eclipse 3.X GWT Opensource setup instructions can be found here 
https://github.com/harikishorekuppa/gwt/blob/master/eclipse/README.txt